# Subtracting specific time in minutes from the time string available

Tags: android, list, datetime

I am developing an application in which there is a scenario that whatever the time I chose, the next part is to subtract 1 minute from the time string and add the new time in minutes to the List. 
For example, this is my code till now:

```
 viewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Date date = (Date) mtablayoutCourtDetailsAvailability.getTabAt(mtablayoutCourtDetailsAvailability.getSelectedTabPosition()).getTag();
                String key = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
                List<String> stringList = stringListMap.get(key);
                if (isChecked)
                {
                   stringList.add(buttonView.getText().toString());
                }

                else
                {
                    stringList.remove(buttonView.getText().toString());
                }

                stringListMap.put(key, stringList);
            }
        });
```

Now in this code, the line below refers to the time that the user will select

```
buttonView.getText().toString()
```

time slots are available like that: "09:00 AM - 10:00 AM"
so whenever any slot is checked there will be some time slot text in buttonView that will be added to list. However, I want to subtract 1 minute from the time that is after "-" i.e. if user select "09:00 AM - 10:00 AM" then the new time that will add in the stringList must be "09:00 AM - 09:59 AM".
Unfortunately, I am unable to achieve this as I am new to this thing. I am able to achieve the second time slot value after "-" with the following code

```
String[] namesList = buttonView.getText().toString().split("-");
        String partbefore= namesList[0];
        String partafter= namesList[1];
```

partafter will contain 10:00 AM which I should change to 09:59 AM after subtracting 1 minute from this. How can I achieve this? Please Help

Comment: Try taking your date value, convert it to milliseconds and add 59 minutes in milliseconds back to it. (1000*60*59). Then convert the new millisecond value using the SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Thankyou for the response @Janwilx72 but i have already time in string available and i want to subtract 1 minute from that time string. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe try something like this:
String finalKey = key + " - " + key.substring(key.length() - 2) + "59";

Comment: @Aarks yes it is possible . i'm posting answer. check it

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to get. set original time as your requirement,

```
try {
        String original_time = "2018-11-11 11:02 am", time_required;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
        SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date date;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = dateFormat.parse(original_time);
        time_required = localDateFormat.format(date);
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);
        time_required = localDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I have solved the issue with almost the same thing as that. Still, thank you and upvote for you.